# Configuring a 1:n relationship in EF Core, using IsRequired()

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In EF Core, many APIs have changed, so I'm confused how to properly configure my relationships.

Suppose one `Book` has many `Page`s, and one `Page` must be part of one `Book` (it cannot exist on its own).

```
builder.Entity<Book>()
  .HasMany(e => e.Pages)
  .WithOne(e => e.Book)
  //.IsRequired()                           // is this, erm, required?
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

I've gone through [the official docs](http://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/relationships.html#required), but I'm still confused about the `.IsRequired()` call for my case as I don't have/need a foreign key in the `Page` entity.

**Is `.IsRequired()` required?**

I assume:

- it refers to the "child"/dependant end of the relationship, i.e. `Page`
- if included then `Book:Pages = 1:0..n`
- if not then `Book:Pages = 0..1:0..n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't include a foreign key property in the `Page` class, EF will create a nullable shadow foreign key property, with a cascade action of NO ACTION. You will have to use the `Required` method to override that if you want the resulting `BookId` column to be configured as not null, and you also need to specify the Cascade action as you have done to ensure that dependants are deleted when the book is deleted.

So the answer to your questions is yes, it is required in your scenario.